# Prove $H_1 \cap H_2 \le H_1 $ when $H_1, H_2 \le G$ and $H_1$, $H_2$ are finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that $H_1 \cap H_2 \le H_1 $ when $H_1, H_2 \le G$ and $H_1$, $H_2$ are finite.

---

**What I've done**

Use the definition of subgroup:  $G$ is a group and $H \subseteq G$.

$H \le G \iff HH=H $ and  $H^{-1}=H$

---

Closure: $\forall h,g \in H_1 \cap H_2$, $gh \in (H_1 \cap H_2)(H_1 \cap H_2)$

$gh \in H_1$ since $g,h\in H_1$ and $H_1$ is a group therefore closure within $H_1$

Similarly, $gh \in H_2$. Hence $gh \in H_1 \cap H_2$.

Using bijectivity of multiplication of elements in group,

$(H_1 \cap H_2)(H_1 \cap H_2)=H_1 \cap H_2$.

$\therefore H_1 \cap H_2 is closed$

Inverse and identity: $(H_1 \cap H_2)^{-1} = \{k^{-1} : k\in H_1 \cap H_2\}$

If $h\in (H_1 \cap H_2)^{-1}$, then $h \in H_1^{-1}=H_1$ and $h \in H_2^{-1}=H_2$

$\therefore h\in H_1 \cap H_2$

Conversely, if $h\in H_1 \cap H_2$ then $h\in H_1^{-1}$ and $h\in H_2^{-1}$.

$\therefore h\in H_1^{-1} \cap H_2^{-1}$

**My question is that whether $H_1^{-1} \cap H_2^{-1} = (H_1 \cap H_2)^{-1}$ and whether "using bijectivity of multiplication of elements in group" is a valid argument**

Comment: The hypothesis that the $H_{i}$ are finite is irrelevant. Simply, the identity is in both $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$, so it is in their intersection. And if $a, b \in H_{i}$, for $i = 1, 2$ then $a b^{-1} \in H_{i}$, so $a b^{-1} \in H_{1} \cap H_{2}$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: The finiteness of $H_1,H_2$ may have been listed as an assumption to enable the use of a simplified subgroup criterion: If $H$ is a **finite** group and $K\subseteq H$ is a non-empty subset such that $KK\subseteq K$, then $K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen and further, $K$ must contain identity too, right? or is $KK \subseteq K$ enough?

Comment: $K$ non-empty and $KK\subseteq K$ is enough. Because $KK\subseteq K$ all the powers of all the elements of $K$ will be in $K$. Because $H$ is finite, all the elements of $K$ have finite order. Consequently the identity and the inverses are **positive** powers. NOTE: It is essential that $H$ is finite for this argument to work.

Comment: @Dosomemaths, I am using the fact that a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup iff it is non empty (equivalently, it contains the identity) and for each $a, b \in H$ we have $a b^{-1} \in H$.