# Proof that if $H_1 \leq G$ and $H_2 \leq G$ then $H_1 \cap H_2 \leq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that

> Prove that if $H_1 \leq G$ and $H_2 \leq G$ then $H_1 \cap H_2 \leq G$

Unlike this question: [Prove $H_1 \cap H_2 \le H_1 $ when $H_1, H_2 \le G$ and $H_1$, $H_2$ are finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875774/prove-h-1-cap-h-2-le-h-1-when-h-1-h-2-le-g-and-h-1-h-2-are-finite) I am not asking to show if the groups are finite and prove the above statement without symbolic logic.

So I went about saying that the identity $e \in H_1, e\in H_2 \iff e\in H_1 \cap H_2$.

Also, if $a \in H_1, a\in H_2 \iff a^{-1} \in H_1 \cap H_2$ since $a^{-1} \in H_1$ and $a^{-1} \in H_2$.

This is the tricky part. I was wondering if my argument was valid here. If $a,b \in H_1 \iff ab \in H_1$. Similar argument for $H_2$. So if $a,b \in H_1 \cap H_2 \iff ab \in H_1 \cap H_2$.

The result follows. Is my argument valid and complete?

Comment: You are not using the symbol  $\Longleftrightarrow$ correctly. It means "if and only if".

Comment: @DerekHolt I believe that's exactly how I want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)\  e \in H_1, H_2$ by subgroup property $\Rightarrow e \in H_1 \cap H_2$

$(2)\ $ If $a \in H_1 \cap H_2 \Rightarrow a \in H_1,H_2 \Rightarrow a^{-1} \in H_1, H_2 \Rightarrow a^{-1} \in H_1 \cap H_2$

$(3)\ $ If $a,b \in H_1 \cap H_2 \Rightarrow a,b \in H_1,H_2 \Rightarrow ab \in H_1, H_2 \Rightarrow ab \in H_1 \cap H_2$

$\bullet$ In general $(H_i)_{1}^n \leq G \Rightarrow \cap_{i=1}^n H_i \leq G$